# Null Column Attribute when inserting values using model binding with array MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

it is my Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ARCCreate(M_ARC[] arcs)
    {
        foreach (M_ARC item in arcs)
        {
            string Year = item.EmailSPDT.ToString().Split('/')[2].Split(' ')[0];
            string Month = item.EmailSPDT.ToString().Split('/')[1];
            int cek = int.Parse(Year + Month);
            ModelState.Remove("Periode");
            item.Periode = cek;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Arcs.Add(item);
            }
            else return View();
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ARCIndex");
    }
```

It is part of my View :

```
                <input type="text" name="arcs[0].InformasiBankDT" class="informasiBankDT" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="arcs[0].Periode" value="201408" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="arcs[0].CreateID" value="@Session["UserID"]" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="arcs[0].UpdateID" value="@Session["UserID"]" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="arcs[0].CreateDT" value="@DateTime.Now" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="arcs[0].UpdateDT" value="@DateTime.Now" />
```

And it is my Model :

```
public class M_ARC
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Periode")]
    [Required]
    public int Periode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email SPDT")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EmailSPDT { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Jatuh Tempo")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime JatuhTempoDT { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Informasi Bank")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime InformasiBankDT { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CreateID")]
    [Required]
    public string CreateID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CreateDT")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateDT { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UpdateID")]
    [Required]
    public string UpdateID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UpdateDT")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime UpdateDT { get; set; }
}
```

And I got exception like this :

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Periode'; column does not allow nulls, INSERT fails, The statement has been terminated

What I must do ? Please Help. Thankyou.

Comment: Are you sure this line doesn't throw an error: `db.Arcs.Add(item);` ? Looks like you're passing an instance of `M_ARC` to EF

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you've posted, the error you have mentioned is not possible.  Periode is an int, which is non-nullable.  It's impossible for it to be a null... it's default value will be a 0.

Is it possible you have more than one M_ARC class and you are referencing the wrong one?  And the other one has a nullable int Periode?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have recheck and the datatype is also Int. ModelState is valid, but when try to save changes after adding, the exception occurred.